# Inconsistency when passing attrib kwarg using cElementTree

Tags: python, python-2.7, elementtree

According to the [ElementTree docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.Element) the interface for `Element()` takes an `attrib` keyword argument.

```
class xml.etree.ElementTree.Element(tag, attrib={}, **extra)
```

This is explained with the following...

> ```
>     attrib is an optional dictionary, containing element attributes.
> ```

Now this works for me as described using Python 2.7 and ElementTree. For example

```
>>> import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
>>> parent = ET.Element("parent")
>>> attribs = {'age': '20', 'name': 'Steve'}
>>> child = ET.SubElement(parent, "child", attrib=attribs)
>>> ET.dump(parent)
<parent><child age="20" name="Steve" /></parent>
```

However when I run the same script but import the `cElementTree` implementation a `TypeError` exception is raised.

```
File "attrib.py", line 17, in <module>
  ET.dump(parent)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1165, in dump
  elem.write(sys.stdout)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 821, in write
  serialize(write, self._root, encoding, qnames, namespaces)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 940, in _serialize_xml
  _serialize_xml(write, e, encoding, qnames, None)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 933, in _serialize_xml
  v = _escape_attrib(v, encoding)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1093, in _escape_attrib
  _raise_serialization_error(text)
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/xml/etree/ElementTree.py", line 1053, in _raise_serialization_error
  "cannot serialize %r (type %s)" % (text, type(text).__name__)
TypeError: cannot serialize {'age': '20', 'name': 'Steve'} (type dict)
```

What am I missing here? Interestingly if I just pass the `attribs` dictionary as a positional argument the cElementTree code works fine.

```
>>> import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
>>> parent = ET.Element("parent")
>>> attribs = {'age': '20', 'name': 'Steve'}
>>> child = ET.SubElement(parent, "child", attribs)
>>> ET.dump(parent)
<parent><child age="20" name="Steve" /></parent>
```

I've found a [bug listed on bugs.python.org](http://bugs.python.org/issue1572710) relating to this - but it is closed with a won't fix resolution. Why is the C implementation behaving differently? Is there any documentation around this I've missed. Thanks

Comment: Not a solution, but relevant: http://bugs.python.org/issue21403

Comment: It is just a straight up implementation difference that is listed as a bug in Python 2.7, but is supposedly fixed in 3.x. It's likely that the "won't fix" in the bug you posted was purely due to dropping python 2.5 support.

Comment: Thanks for the link Alok - this makes a bit more sense now and confirms it is a bug in 2.7.